# R: Splitting dgCMatrix into train and test matrices, to use for XGBoost training

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-data, xgboost

First of all, I am new to XGBoost. So pardon my stupidity.

Here is the question:

How can I split a dgCMatrix into two matrices (say, train and test)? My aim is to use these matrices for XGBoost training. I got the dgCMatrix when I converted all of my categorical variables into numerical variables using one-hot encoding. Can I do one-hot encoding separately on the training dataset and test dataset?

I have tried dummyVars (from the package caret) for one-hot encoding, but my R session is getting aborted for some reason which I don't know.

Comment: How are you creating your `dgCMatrix`? If you go via a regular numeric or sparse matrix, you can subset as you would any other R object and then make two `dgCMatrix`'s.

Comment: @DexGroves.. Thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply. I am using the function `sparse.model.matrix` from `Matrix` package to create the `dgCMatrix`. As you said, if I split the regular matrix into train and test first and then convert both into `dgCMatrix`, will both matrices have same one hot encoding?

Comment: By the point you have a matrix, isn't the one hot encoding already done? Matrices have to be one datatype (usually float). Does your matrix still contain categorical information somehow?

Comment: @DexGroves Sorry, what I have is a `data frame`, not a matrix. I want to get a `train dgCMatrix` and a `test dgCMatrix` from this data frame. I can split the data frame into two and then convert both to dgCMatrices. But won't the one hot encoding be different for those two matrices? Other solution is to convert the whole data frame to dgCMatrix and then split that dgCMatrix into two dgCMatrices, which I don't know how to do. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your categorical information is encoded as a factor and that will work. [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235764/new-factors-levels-not-present-in-training-data/235767#235767) has additional details. Alternatively you can make the whole thing into a sparse matrix, split that, and make two dgcMatrices.

Comment: @DexGroves.. Now I understood it. Even if we split dataset into two (say, A and B), information about all levels of a factor will be stored in both A and B even if some of the levels are not present in either A or B. So when we do one hot encoding on a subset, it encodes all the levels irrespective of whether the levels are present in the subset or not. And it uses the same encoding on the next subset. This is what I understood and I hope it is correct. Thanks a lot for helping. If you add this as an answer, I can accept it. :)

Comment: Yep, you explained it very succinctly. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding DexGroves's comment here as an answer since it answers the question.

> Even if you split your dataset into two (say, A and B), the information about
>   all levels of a factor will be stored in both A and B even if some of
>   the levels are not present in either A or B. So when you do one hot
>   encoding on a subset, it encodes all the levels irrespective of
>   whether the levels are present in the subset or not. And it uses the
>   same encoding on the next subset.